# Camunda History and Audit Event Log, I can't query any history data

Tags: camunda

I have been running Camunda with MariaDB, it's a good solution

but I have a problem, I saw the Camunda User Guide that describes History and Audit Event Log, so I write some codes as follows:

List historyList = historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().finished().processDefinitionId("Sample1").list();

int historySize = historyList.size();

LOGGER.info("historyList size=" + historySize);

I have finished the Sample1 Process, but the historySize still is zero, I think I lost some configuration, how can I do?

Wnat's difference between Runtime Database and Histort Database? do I need to install two Databases?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem by using processDefinitionKey

I passed processDefinitionKey to processDefinitionId, no wonder it can't get all finished instances of a process

I can get all finished instances of a process using correct processDefinitionId or processDefinitionKey